# how to read s3 files from apache beam python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam python SDK to read s3 file data.

code I am using

```
    ip = (pipe
          | beam.io.ReadFromText("s3://bucket_name/file_path")
          | beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(","))
          | beam.Map(print)

          )
```

but it gives a error

```
 S3ClientError('Unable to locate credentials', None)}")}
```

Anybody have any idea how to give credentials to s3 client thorugh apache beam python file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the credentials are available on your worker machines. One way to do this is installing them in a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers).

Comment: can we do the same for AWS S3?

Comment: Yes, you can install AWS S3 credentials in the container.

Comment: thanks for telling, can you update your answer according